# Python: Save page's dynamic image

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to programmatically load contents of a HTML page which has a dynamic image in its body.  Then I want to download and save this image as it shows THAT time in THAT page load.

Example of the image in HTML:

```
<img src="image.php">
```

The thing is I cant just fetch contents of the PHP script at `http://example.com/image.php` because it will just generate and return me another image, not the same image generated in the original page.

So, how to save image generated in that page? I know i can't use [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) because it opens an actual browser window. I'm considering to use [zope.testbrowser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testbrowser) or maybe [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), but cound't find any info on how to do it.

Could you guys help me?

Comment: How are you loading the HTML page the first time?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yes I did, using mechanize and cookielib. Posting full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using mechanize, cookielib and urllib.

First, set the imports and the headless browser handlers:

```
# Mechanize headless
import mechanize
import cookielib
import urllib
# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()
# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
# Want debugging messages?
#br.set_debug_http(True)
#br.set_debug_redirects(True)
#br.set_debug_responses(True)
```

Add "human" headers so you're not mistaken for a bot...

```
# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
```

Now you can just normally "navigate" using `open` method. Dynamic images can also be loaded with `open`. Just follow page/files hierarchy sequence and mechanize/cookielib will handle the headers for you...

```
r = br.open('http://www.example.com/html-page-with-dynamic-image-embedded.html')

# Check if HTML content returned ok
if br.response().info()['Content-Type'] == 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1':
    # Now that the main page is loaded you can open the dynamic image
    r = br.open('http://www.example.com/images/image.php')

    # From here you just treat the image as you wish
    png = r.read()
    f = open('image-new-name.png', 'wb')
    f.write(png)
    f.close()
```

Urllib is used if you need to send URL GET data like this

```
data = {'varName1': var1, 'varName2': var2, ...}
data = urllib.urlencode(data)
r = br.open('http://www.example.com/html-page-with-dynamic-image-embedded.html', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Im still a beginner - but I have used [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) in a similiar case, to download pictures from a website.

It should be easy to get the image with this library.